# change values of a dictionary in a list, while preserving the existing list

Tags: list, dictionary

list1 = [{'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1', 'c': 'c1'}]

if I want to change 'a1' value to a2, how can i do that?

also, with changing a1 to a2, I also have to preserve list1 and make new list.

there are no any questions about this in this site....

Answer (score 0):

There are not lists, they are dictionaries. You don't need the square brackets.

```
dict1 = {'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1', 'c': 'c1'}
```

To copy a dictionary use `.copy()`

```
dict2 = dict1.copy()
```

To replace the value of keyname `a` use.

```
dict2['a'] = 'a2'

print(dict1)
print(dict2)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1', 'c': 'c1'}
{'a': 'a2', 'b': 'b1', 'c': 'c1'}
```

If, for some reason, you do really want your dictionary inside a list, you can modify the values by addressing it's position in the list and then the dictionary key. In your case, there is one dictionary with index 0 in the list.

```
dict2[0]['a'] = 'a2'
```